# How to extrude a face until it intersects with another object?

Tags: extrude, intersection

what I want to achieve: I want to extrude a face until it hits another object so that a clean seam is produced. I read as a suggestion to use Tool/Options/Auto Merge and "Split edges and faces", but it's not producing the desired result. I would be happy if there is a solution. Of course, even if this "auto merge and split edges and faces" would have worked, I would have to clean up "inner faces". That would be ok. If required, I can provide an example blender file to experiment with.

First image shows the face to be extruded. Second image shows the result from "Auto merge".

[image: This face I want to "extrude"]

[image: That's the result]